# No puedo instalar weblogic 12c en Mac M1

Tags: macos, weblogic, oracle-12c, arm

Me compre mi mac m1, pero no he podido instalar weblogic 12c, instale java 8 y cuando ejecuto en la terminal con rosetta el siguiente codigo

```
java -jar fmw_12.1.3.0.0_wls.jar
```

me aparece el siguiente error

```
El archivo log del iniciador es /private/var/folders/km/tqp3cxcs3jg03bf9c3vgwcjh0000gn/T/OraInstall2021-12-01_01-10-06PM/launcher2021-12-01_01-10-06PM.log.

Extrayendo archivos.....

Este Installer se debe ejecutar mediante un Java Development Kit (JDK) pero /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home no es un JDK válido.
```

Comment: La pregunta no tiene relación con temas de programación.

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes descargar el Java Developer Kit para iOS de la página oficial de Oracle (https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk17-mac), y descarga el ARM 64 DMG Installer. Una vez completados los pasos del instalador, en la consola utiliza:

`javac -version`

Para comprobar que se ha instalado correctamente.
Una vez hecho esto debería funcionar el instalador que quieras utilizar.